# Trying to make a basic snake game using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a basic snake-like game using Swift, but i'm having trouble making the tail of the snake follow the head. I know the traditional way is to delete the tail, and place a new snake part at the top of the snake in order to simulate movement, only changing the first and last parts of the snake (array). The problem I'm running into, is that because my game is not grid-based, the movement is more continuous/fluid, and I'm having trouble adjusting for the snake body movement.

Below is one of my snake movement methods, as well as the method to adjust the body accordingly. My logic is to move the head, and then have all of the body parts adjust accordingly, however it's not working as planned. I'm very new to SpriteKit and this is my first attempted game. If someone could explain the logic given the fluid snake movement and grid-less environment, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

```
func moveUp(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
{
    dir = "U"
    snakeHead.removeAllActions()
    let moveUp = SKAction.moveByX(0.0, y: snakeHead.size.height, duration: 0.5)
    snakeHead.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveUp))
}

func followTheLeader()
{
    for var i=0;i<snake.count-1;i++
    {
        var snakeToFollow = snake[i]
        var moveToX = snakeToFollow.position.x
        var moveToY = snakeToFollow.position.y

        var moveTo = CGPointMake(moveToX, moveToY)
        var snakeToMove = snake[i+1]
        snakeToMove.position = moveTo
    }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)
{
    followTheLeader()        
}
```

**EDIT - Grow Snake Method**

```
func growSnake()
{
    var length = snake.count
    var last:SKSpriteNode = snake[length-1]

    var lastX = last.position.x
    var lastY = last.position.y

    var body = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor(red: (255/255.0), green: (102/255.0), blue: (102/255.0), alpha: 1.0), size: CGSizeMake(20.0, 20.0))
    body.position = CGPointMake(lastX, lastY-22.0)
    body.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: snakeHead.size)
    body.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    body.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Snake
    body.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall | PhysicsCategory.Food
    body.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall
    body.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0

    addChild(body)

    snake.append(body)
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what happens currently?

Comment: currently, when extra snake parts are added, they just layer on top of the current snake head's position. If i try adding a buffer of snake size to moveToY, it positions them correctly, but won't allow for lateral movement, or "bends" in the snake shape when I attempt to move sideways. Instead it moves the entire line of snake parts sideways instead of one at a time at the "bend point".

Comment: From the code I see in your followTheLeader function, after the loop is completed, all the snake body parts will have the same position.If you went through the array in reverse, they'd move to the position of the body part before them in the array - BEFORE that body part moves to it's new location. Which is I think what you want.

Comment: Also, I don't see the code that adjusts the first body part to a new location based on the head.

Comment: @prototypical I just tried your suggesting of looping in reverse, and there was still overlap between the body parts, although it wasn't as bad. More like half of each part overlapped instead of them on top of one another. Do you have any more suggestions? Thanks for the response! Also, to hopefully clear things up a bit, the array contains the snakeHead at index 0, the moveUp function moves only the snakeHead. Then the rest of the body parts are supposed to adjust their positions accordingly based off the skspritenode at index 0 which is the snakeHead that moves.

Comment: well, I didn't say your approach would work, haha. I was just saying that I don't think you were doing what you were thought you were doing. If your snake isn't moving, eventually they will all be overlapping each other. Another body part per frame.

Comment: I believe your approach did actually work, haha. I just need a little additional buffer between the parts that it's not currently giving me. And you were right I wasn't doing what I thought I was doing, I needed to go through the array in reverse like you said. The snake and all the parts are moving, the only issue now is that the parts overlap on half the part in front of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66966/discussion-between-prototypical-and-user3353890).

Comment: Did you consider using `SKConstraint` to construct the snake?

Comment: No I haven't. I'll take a look into it

Answer (score 0):

In your `followTheLeader` function you are moving the `snakeHead` using an SKAction which lasts 0.5 seconds. Then every update call, you move each part of the snake to position of the one in front of it. This will lead to a pileup as you described in your comment after a few updates. I would suggest not using the SKAction at all and just moving the position of the `snakeHead` in the `update` function. Here is a sample implementation:

Create `xSpeed` and `ySpeed` properties of the scene.

```
var xSpeed = 1
var ySpeed = 0
```

Then use them to move the `snakeHead` in the `update` function.

```
snakeHead.position = CGPointMake(snakeHead.position.x + xSpeed, snakeHead.position.y + ySpeed);
```

Then, if you want to change the direction of the snake you could just change the `xSpeed` and `ySpeed`.

```
func moveUp(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
{
    ySpeed = 1
    xSpeed = 0
}
```

Comment: Just saw this. I have to run out of the house for a bit, but i'll test it when I get home. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I was just able to try it out...unfortunately I still get the pile up :/

Comment: Is the pileup moving up the screen?

Comment: Yes, the pileup is moving up the screen along with the snake head. It moved up the screen with the skaction as well. I also have down, left, and right methods for movement, but they're so similar to the moveUp method I didn't bother posting them. Just additional information. The pile up moves in every direction however

Comment: This method of moving the snake requires that the initial position of the body is a line, with no pileups. Is this the case?

Comment: the initial position of the snake is a single body part. the snake body parts are stored in an array. as the snake runs into food, it grows by adding body parts after the position of the last snake part in the array. I'll add my grow snake method above.